# How to fix cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12514: TNS:listener error

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, python-3.6

I use python 3.6 (32bit) and I use Oracle database 11g, I want to connect my python to oracle database. This is my version oracle for python cx-Oracle==7.2.1

This is my `file.ORA` :

```
myservice = (DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=
    (PROTOCOL=tcp)
    (HOST=localhost)
    (PORT= ))
(CONNECT_DATA=
    (SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))
```

This is My Code:

```
import cx_Oracle
con= cx_Oracle.connect("db_employees/root@localhost/orcl")
cur= conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select*from employess')
for line in cur:
    print(line)
cur.close()
con.close()
```

But it shows errors. This is my errors messages:

```
C:\Python36>python "D:\bisa.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\bisa.py", line 3, in <module>
     con= cx_Oracle.connect("db_employees/root@localhost/orcl")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: What connector did you use ?

Comment: i use connector oracle

Comment: What version ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in .ORA file

```
myservice =
   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <<validhostname>>)(PORT = <<validportnumber>>))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = <<servicenameofDB>>)
    )
)
```

Comment: Why not just use Oracle's  "Easy Connect" syntax as the original question had?: `validhostname:validportnumber/servicenameofDB`. There is no need for tnsnames.ora file. For example `con= cx_Oracle.connect("db_employees/root@validhostname:validportnumber/servicenameofDB")`

Comment: Because .ora file's alias are reusable. @christopher

Comment: SQL*Net .ora files are an extra (error prone) configuration step for newbies.  They a fine for non-beginners, and definitely needed in some cases.